# Power Query read multiple ranges from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have attaches "simple" excel file as an example. Three sheets on each sheet we have either: one, two, three of four ranges with data (there are not tables). Originally the file has 21 sheets with different number of ranges with data on each sheet. All sheets are the same format. I want to have ONE consolidated table. So if in sheet PL we have three ranges I want them one by one then from sheet DE we have two ranges I want them below last entry from PL and so on...

[Example Excel file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!As0TuaNRMbDLi5ISr2T2kZg8MXrJqQ?e=WScUfa)

As you see in the last sheet TOTAL in column "I" and "W" I have those tables but I want then connected not in columns but those ranges I want appended in the bottom after row 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  This will work on a workbook without Tables or Named Ranges.

1. Get Data > From File > From Workbook.  Select the workbook name and
   choose Transform Data
2. Select the Data column.  Right-click, Remove Other Columns
3. Click the double arrows to expand the columns.  Deselect the "Use Original Column Name as Prefix" checkbox.
4. Home tab > Use First Row as Headers
5. Open the Advanced Editor and add these two steps:

   ```
   #"RemovedColumnList" = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), each Text.StartsWith(_, "Column")),
   #"RemovedColumns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type", RemovedColumnList),
   ```
6. Filter the ID column to Does Not Equal "ID"
7. Transform tab > Unpivot Columns
8. Select the Attribute column, choose Extract from the Transform tab.  Extract text before delimiter, use "_" as the delimiter.
9. Add Column > Index Column > From 1
10. Open the Advanced Editor, insert this step:

```
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Index",each [Index], each Number.RoundUp([Index]/5),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Index"}),
```

11. Select the Attribute column.  Transform tab > Pivot Column.  Choose Value for the Values Column.  Click Advanced, select Do Not Aggregate from the dropdown.
12. Select the Index column and remove.

Full M Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Jody.Highroller\Documents\excel\Copy of ExampleFinal.xlsx"), null, true),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Data"}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Data", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29", "Column30", "Column31"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29", "Column30", "Column31"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Expanded Data", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ID", type any}, {"Name", type text}, {"Status 1", type any}, {"Status 2", type any}, {"Collection", type text}, {"Column6", type any}, {"Column7", type any}, {"Column8", type any}, {"ID_1", type any}, {"Name_2", type text}, {"Status 1_3", type any}, {"Status 2_4", type any}, {"Collection_5", type text}, {"Column14", type any}, {"Column15", type any}, {"Column16", type any}, {"Column17", type any}, {"ID_6", type any}, {"Name_7", type text}, {"Status 1_8", type any}, {"Status 2_9", type any}, {"Collection_10", type text}, {"Column23", type any}, {"Column24", type any}, {"Column25", type any}, {"Column26", type any}, {"ID_11", Int64.Type}, {"Name_12", type text}, {"Status 1_13", Int64.Type}, {"Status 2_14", Int64.Type}, {"Collection_15", type text}}),
    RemovedColumnList = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), each Text.StartsWith(_, "Column")),
    #"RemovedColumns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type", RemovedColumnList),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(RemovedColumns, each ([ID] <> "ID")),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns", {{"Attribute", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "_"), type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Index",each [Index], each Number.RoundUp([Index]/5),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Replaced Value", List.Distinct(#"Replaced Value"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. This file is changing every month. So doing that job manually (change range into name or table) is not good choice, changing 21 sheets with 2 up to 4 ranges in every sheet. I had those ranges as table - the task would be obvious. But I have what I have: 21 sheets with many ranges on each sheet - no tables or names ranges :(

Comment: Neat solution. I think it would be a good idea to first filter the source to select the sheets only, excluding the TOTAL worksheet, in case one or more sheets were to be updated (or a named range added) after an initial consolidation is executed. Also, the empty columns do not need to be removed seeing as all those null values are removed in the unpivot step.

Comment: Thanks for the protip @Patrick FitzGerald that saves two steps that wouldn't be done using the GUI.  My assumption is this would be run from a separate workbook than that in which the data is present, but I agree with your sentiment.